# Django authentication not working for browser

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am trying to use django's inbuilt authentication system for my application.

I'm able to authenticate a user during login but, for the following requests **request.user.is_authenticated** is coming as **False**

**login view:**

```
 user_name = request_body['username']
 password = request_body['password']
 user = authenticate(username=user_name, password=password)
 if user is not None:
   login(request, user)
   request.session.set_expiry(86940)
```

I've written a decorator to check authentication, the code is:

```
 from django.http import HttpResponse

def authenticate_request(f):

    def check(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:   #coming as false even after authenication is done
            return f(request)
        else:
            return HttpResponse(status=401)

    return check
```

What am I missing while authenticating the request?

Comment: Is the login view named "login"?

Comment: @iain no, it is 'login_user'

Answer (score 0):

Check your current SESSION_COOKIE_AGE and make sure that you dont overwrite it somewhere else in you program. Make sure that you dont immediately get logged out. The default value of SESSION_COOKIE_AGE is 1209600 (2 weeks, in seconds).

Comment: I'm not overriding SESSION_COOKIE_AGE key anywhere